# Is it possible to login with an azure ad account, via the azure cli while running as the "NT Authority\Network Service" user?

Tags: windows, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-service-fabric, azure-cli

I work in a team that uses Azure Service Fabric and I want to connect to an Azure SQL database using my Azure AD account instead of using a SQL username/password when running locally.

Service Fabric runs locally on a cluster and runs as the `NT Authority\Network Service` user. I believe that it's possible to change the user that it runs under, but when I tried it seemed to remove the ability to use Visual Studio to debug the app. It also required having the password in the config which is not ideal.

I'm trying to login to Azure AD with the AzureCli and the `az login` command and can do this easily with my local user `azuread\chester`.

A [comment on github](https://github.com/microsoft/service-fabric/issues/1299#issuecomment-1251921205) suggests that I should be able to run a powershell prompt as the network service and use `az login` to login with my account. When I tried this it failed with a generic error:

[image]

Does anyone know if it's possible to login to AzureAD with the `NT Authority\Network Service` user?

I know it's possible to use an Azure App Registration as a principal, but this method still involves a password and i'm trying to avoid passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible but, since it's a non-interactive account, the optimal choice is [to login as an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). This, however, implies high level permissions so careful attention must be paid when consenting them. Also, it's possible to login as a user using the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), however this one is not recommended due security and technical limitations.

Regarding az cli take a look at [Sign in with a service principal.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli#sign-in-with-a-service-principal)